# C++/ build project got errors

Tags: c++

I have the next files in c++ in Visual Studio 2010:

```
stdafx.h


// stdafx.h : include file for standard system include files,
// or project specific include files that are used frequently, but
// are changed infrequently
//
#pragma once

#include "targetver.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>

void printHello();
// TODO: reference additional headers your program requires here
```

inter.cpp

```
// Inter.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    printHello();
}
```

stdafx.cpp

```
// stdafx.cpp : source file that includes just the standard includes
// Inter.pch will be the pre-compiled header
// stdafx.obj will contain the pre-compiled type information

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

// TODO: reference any additional headers you need in STDAFX.H
// and not in this file
void printHello() {
    std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;  
}
```

and I got it:

```
'Inter.exe': Loaded 'C:\Users\Adamsh\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Inter\Debug\Inter.exe', Symbols loaded.
'Inter.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Inter.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Inter.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcp100d.dll', Symbols loaded.
'Inter.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcr100d.dll', Symbols loaded.
The program '[3636] Inter.exe: Native' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: That looks perfectly normal to me assuming you don't have debugging information for ntdll and kernel32.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: The last lines are problem, no? Beacuse I don't see the "Hello world!" output

Comment: @AdamSh your console probably closes before you get a chance to see your message.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: So what to do?

Comment: @AdamSh since this is MSVS, run through the program pressing F10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAICS there's nothing *technically* wrong with your program as a Visual C++ specific program.

However, it is needlessly compiler specific.

In particular, replace your Visual C++ specific and hopelessly meaningless monstrosity

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
```

with a standard C++

```
int main()
```

For debugging your program, in Visual Studio choose a "Debug" build instead of "Release".

**EDIT**: Folks in the Lounge commented about maybe the program is finishing too fast for the OP? If so, just place a breakpoint on the closing brace of `main`.